# bash echo >> does not work

Tags: bash, echo

I would like to write a string into a file but it does not work. I am sure that I miss something trivial. The files do not exist yet. 
Why does the script below does not write anything in the files? The files are not even created.

```
#!/bin/bash

j="nch"
temp_dir="~/temp_temp"
echo "$temp_dir/$j"
echo "c'mon" >> "$temp_dir/$j"
echo "c'mon" >> "~/temp_temp/pch"
```

Comment: Debug using `sh -x script.sh`; it shows you what the shell is doing and would help you see what was going wrong.  You might also have noted what the first `echo` generated on your screen; that would have pointed you in the right direction too.

Answer (score 5):

`~` is not expanded in quoted strings.

```
temp_dir=~/temp_temp
echo "c'mon" >> ~/temp_temp/pch
```

or

```
temp_dir=~/"temp_temp"
echo "c'mon" >> ~/"temp_temp/pch"
```

etc.

Comment: Right. I missed that. Thanks!

Comment: You can also use `$HOME`, which is expanded within quoted strings.  But in general, it helps to remember that quotation marks are not token boundaries in the shell; `foo` is the same as `"foo"` or `"f"o"o"` or `f"oo"`, etc.  The stuff inside the quotes is interpreted differently, but changing from inside to outside doesn't end the word.